# google map api intergration with vue cli

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I have integrated google map api with my vue cli project

```
import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps';
    Vue.config.productionTip = false;
    Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
      load: {
        key: 'mykey',
        libraries: 'places', // necessary for places input
      },
    });
```

but the google map is showing up and getting disabled with the message something went wrong any idea what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to google cloud platform and enable all maps related API's
If you haven't enabled all related api it will behave like this.